# How to set the parameterized constructor value

Tags: c#

I want to set the parameterized constructor value (aName and aValue) to attribName and attribValue set method, please assist.

```
public class PlayerRow
{
    public PlayerRow(string aName, string aValue)
    {
      AttribsPlayerLine = new List<AttribLine>();
    }
    public List<AttribLine> AttribsPlayerLine { get; set; }

    public class AttribLine
    {

    [Description("AttribName")]
    public string attribName { get; set; }

    [Description("AttribValue")]
    public string attribValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `attribName = aValue;` not work?

Comment: You have two classes here. The constructor and properties exist in different classes. You want to use constructor of `PlayerRow` class to set properties of  `AttribLine` and add it to collection?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing what are you trying to achieve here, if you can clarify we can help better. But here is my answer if I understood correctly, if not please comment and i will edit my answer.

```
public class PlayerRow
{
    public PlayerRow(string aName, string aValue)
    {
        AttribsPlayerLine = new List<AttribLine>();

        AttribLine temp = new AttribLine();
        temp.attribName = aName;
        temp.attribValue = aValue;
        AttribsPlayerLine.Add(temp);
    }
    public List<AttribLine> AttribsPlayerLine { get; set; }

    public class AttribLine
    {

    [Description("AttribName")]
    public string attribName { get; set; }

    [Description("AttribValue")]
    public string attribValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I don't really see any benefits in this, as the constructor will add only 1 item to the list. Though, you can still access PlayerRow object in your main and then access AttribsPlayerLine and then add a new AttribLine to it. But to us it's not clear.